# Is there an R function for creating a new column to the existing data frame and assign "03" to first 68 rows and "04" to next 68 rows?

Tags: r

The current data frame has three columns and 136 rows.  I want to create a new column  with first 68 rows have a fixed value="03" and next 68 rows have a fixed value='04".

select(code, year, value) ->aa1.
I tried this code
aa1 [ , 'month']=  c(rep( '03','1:68'))

aa1 [ , 'month']=  c(rep( '04', '69:136'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use rep

```
x$newvar <- c( rep( "03", 68) , rep( "04", 68) )
```

Or index

```
x$newvar2 <- NA
x[ 1:68  , "newvar2" ] <- "03"
x[ 69:136  , "newvar2" ] <- "04"
```

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this? You need to use rep twice in this case:

```
aa1[ , 'month']= c(rep('03', 68), rep('04', 68))
```

Comment: YOu can do this in one step `rep(c('03', '04'),  each = 68)`

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Maybe it is a little less transparent to a complete beginner but I agree that it is shorter at least